# Why did my cat attack my face while I slept?

Tags: cats, behavior

My cat attacked me while I was asleep. It felt like someone threw him on me and he used his claws/paws to land on my face. Somehow he scratched the top and lower part of my arm and my thigh before he ran away. I jumped off my bed and screamed.

He usually sleeps at the foot of my bed. Please help me to understand what could've took place. He ran away shortly after, for the second time. He's only one year old.

Answer (score 2):

Your cat did have a normal reaction to movement. You moved and the cat got triggered by this movement (when one sleeps the muscles in your face can move and this can trigger your cat's hunting/play reaction). When you play with your cat, you trigger the same reaction only then it is wanted.

Cats sometimes do get triggered if you move your toes or fingers while you are asleep, but normally the cat does stop doing this after some time as your reaction to this is a negative one for the cat.

So your cat is not broken. It is just reacting normally to movement, and it will stop doing this when it sees you reacting negative to it.

you can help the cat stop doing this by playing more during the day leaving less unreleased energy in your cat(if a cat do hunt/play too little it will get frustrated and have sudden bursts of energy)here in norway we call this raptuser.